# Counting loops in Python when skipping numbers

Tags: python, for-loop, counting

How many loops will the following for loop have?

```
for i in range(1, 5, 2):
     print(i, end=" ")
```

I know that the output is "1 3", but I'm not exactly certain how it goes through, if it loops for each. My gut wants to say 2 loops.

1. 1, skip 2
2. 3, skip 4 and reach end of range.

Is this correct thinking?

Comment: Divide the number of elements in the sequential range by 2.

Comment: And round up if there's a fraction.

Comment: Don't think of it in terms of skipping numbers. The last argument to `range()` is the amount that's added to each element to get the next one. So start with `1`, next is `1+2`, next is `1+2+2`, and so on until you reach 5 or more.

Comment: Divide number of elements by 2... so that'd be 4 elements / 2 = 2? The 4 elements being 1, 2, 3, 4. "and so on until you reach 5 or more" but 5 is the stopping number, so 4 is the last number that counts... no?

Comment: Right. `ceil((5-1)/2) == 2`